# Android Usability Testing Setup (ddms, screenshots, touchevent)

Tags: android, usability, logcat, ddms

im thinking of an **easy-to-use android usability testing tool**, that will allow the user to record and log relevant information during app testing. As a first result i would like to have **a screenshot taken each time the user interacts with the touchscreens** where the position, duration and type of the touch event is shown.

As android does not allow me to take screenshots easily and as its not possible to log touchevents from an service here are my questions:

1. Does **Logcat** give me any **information about TouchEvents** (I tried but i couldt produce any touch-Logs)
2. Is it possible to **evoke the ddms-Screenshot-action from terminal**? (./ddms -takescreenshot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Logcat give me any information about TouchEvents (I tried but i couldt produce any touch-Logs)

No.

> Is it possible to evoke the ddms-Screenshot-action from terminal? (./ddms -takescreenshot)

Not via the `ddms` command AFAIK. Either use `monkeyrunner` (as another answer suggested), or write your own code to the JAR file that DDMS uses. I used that to create a software projector; another developer [extended that concept](http://blog.ribomation.com/droid-at-screen/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to automate these things, you can use the Monkey Runner tool, it specifically has a call to take screen shots automatically.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html

It specifically runs Python scripts, that you would use to design an automated regression test.